# random probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the discrete random variables $Y,X$ with supports $\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{X}$.

Suppose that the probability measure of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ is itself a discrete random variable with support $\mathcal{A}_{y}$ for any $y\in \mathcal{Y}$ (random probability measure).

Let $P_{X|y}(x)$ be the probability measure of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ evaluated at $X=x$.

Let $P_{Y, P_{X|y}}(y_1,a)$ be the joint probability measure of $Y,P_{X|y}$ evaluated at $Y=y_1$, $P_{X|y}(x)=a$.

**Questions**:

(1) **Should** $P_{X|y}(x)$, $X$ and $Y$ be random variables defined on two different probability spaces (one for $P_{X|y}(x)$ and one for $X$ and $Y$)? Could you explain what happens if we use the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P}, \mathcal{F})$ to define all the three random variables?

What I am confused about is the following: let $X,Y$ be defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P}, \mathcal{F})$.

$X$ induces the probability measure $P_X$ such that $P_X(B)=\mathbb{P}(\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } X(\omega)\in B)$ $\forall B\in \mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra

Similarly, $Y$ induces the probability measure $P_Y$ such that $P_Y(B)=\mathbb{P}(\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } Y(\omega)\in B)$ $\forall B\in \mathcal{B}$

Lastly, $P_{X|y}(B)=\mathbb{P}(\omega \in \Omega_y \text{ s.t. } X(\omega)\in B)$ $\forall B\in \mathcal{B}$, where $\Omega_y:=\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } Y(\omega)=y\}$.

How can $P_{X|y}(B)$ be defined on $(\Omega, \mathbb{P}, \mathcal{F})$ too?

(2) Is $P_{Y, P_{X|y}}(y_1,a)=0$ by definition?

Comment: Why is $P_{X|y}$ a random variable in your opinion ? It seems to be that it is a function  $\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}^+$.
Furthermore, why do you say that $\mathcal{X}$ is the support of $X$ ?
The support of a function is something else, isn't $X$ a function $\Omega \to \mathcal{X} $ ?

Comment: Is an assumption (see definition.of random probability measure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a random measure is to be thought of as the conditional distribution of a random variable $X$, then in a way $X$ is a 'random' random variable, and it's hard to separate the different layers of randomness when we talk about $X$.

In your context we are discussing the joint distribution of $Y$ and $P_{X|y}$. This means that necessarily these two objects are defined on the same probability space. As for $X$, notice that $X$ is not explicitly defined here except in terms of its *distribution*. For example consider a discrete probability space $(\Omega, {\mathbb P}, {\cal F})$ with three objects:

$$
\begin{array}{cccl}
\omega&{\mathbb P}(\omega)&Y(\omega)&P_{X|y}(\omega)\\
\hline
\omega_1&1/4&0&\text{Bernoulli}(p=0)\\
\omega_2&1/4&0&\text{Bernoulli}(p=1)\\
\omega_3&1/2&1&\text{Bernoulli}(p=1/2)\\
\end{array}
$$
This specification is enough to determine $P_{X|y}(x)$, which is a *random variable* defined by
$$P_{X|y}(x)(\omega):=P_{X|y}(\omega)(\{x\});$$
to emphasize that $P_{X|y}(x)$ is a random variable for each $x$, we could fill out the above table with two additional columns $P_{X|y}(0)(\omega)$ and $P_{X|y}(1)(\omega)$. Similarly the *random measure* $P_{X|y}(\cdot)$ is defined by
$$
P_{X|y}(B)(\omega):=\sum_{x\in B}P_{X|y}(x)(\omega);
$$
to answer your first question, that's how we define $P_{X|y}(B)$; note that $P_{X|y}(B)$ is a random variable for each $B$.

To answer your second question, no, $P_{Y, P_{X|y}}(y_1,a)$ is not zero by definition. In the discrete probability space defined above, $Y$ has two possible values (namely $0$ and $1$), and $P_{X|y}$ has three possible values (namely, three flavors of the Bernoulli distribution). The joint probabilities of all possible combinations of these will be $0$, or $1/4$, or $1/2$, depending on how you match up $y_1$ and $a$.

Comment: Thanks, I have one doubt that I really do not get. In the table: since $\mathcal{Y}:=\{0,1\}$ in your example, should there be one column for $P_{X|y=0}(\omega)$ and one column for $P_{X|y=1}(\omega)$? Or I should read it in the following way: the entry (2,4) of the table is $P_{X|Y(\omega_1)}(\omega_1)$ i.e.  $P_{X|0}(\omega_1)$, the entry (3,4) of the table is $P_{X|Y(\omega_2)}(\omega_2)$ i.e.  $P_{X|0}(\omega_2)$, the entry (4,4) of the table is $P_{X|Y(\omega_3)}(\omega_3)$ i.e.  $P_{X|1}(\omega_3)$?

Comment: Lastly, and possibly related to my first question, how does $P_{X|y}$ varies with $y$ in the example?

Comment: And also, how do you get $0,\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}$ in the last line of your answer.

Comment: I think here I have a second layer of difficulties that is the condition on $Y$. I have asked a simpler version of this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244089/implications-of-having-a-random-probability-measure

Comment: @STF Good point, in $P_{Y, P_{X|y}}(y_1,a)$ it's unclear what is the connection between $y_1$ and $P_{X|y}$, i.e., whether it's true that the $y$ in $P_{X|y}$ is supposed to equal $y_1$. That was my assumption (so your second reading is what I understood), but maybe that's not what the author intended. Under my interpretation, $P_{X|y}(\omega)$ is locked to the value of $Y(\omega)$, so in my example, only three combinations of the possible values for $Y$ and $P_{X|y}$ have nonzero probability; the other three have zero prob.

Comment: @STF As for the interpretation of $P_X$, with this setup it's no longer obvious to me how we should define $P_X(B)$, so I've deleted that discussion from my answer.  Is there any additional context in your setup that might shed some light on this?

Comment: My question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244089/definettis-representation-theorem-for-infinite-sequences could help to clarify things